# How to number each row in UITableIVew?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, storyboard

I have a UITableView and am programmatically adding new rows to it.. How can I number each row? Is there a storybard option for this?

Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Storyboard isn't a replacement for learning to code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no “storyboard option” to number the rows, assuming you mean you want the rows to display their row numbers on the screen.

In `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, you need to set the text of a label to contain the cell's row number.  For example:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Row %d", indexPath.row];
```

If you don't understand that line of code, or don't understand where to put it, you need to work through some table view tutorials before proceeding.